# Gerar patch com diff entre dois branchs

Tags: git

Tenho que gerar um Patch das alterações que fiz.

O problema é que tenho 2 branchs e tenho que gerar o patch dos arquivos do Branch2 em relação a diff do Branch1 (que é onde estão os arquivos originais).

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem problema se os commits estão em branches diferentes. O que você precisa é apenas saber o hash de cada commit. E aí é só rodar o seguinte comando:

```
git diff <hash-1> <hash-2> > <nome-do-patch>.patch
```

Para aplicar o patch, o comando é:

```
git apply --check <nome-do-patch>.patch
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas uma dúvida: estive pesquisando, para gerar o patch não seria algo como: `git format-patch master --stdout > [nome do arquivo].patch` ? Ou da no mesmo?

Comment: Provavelmente é a mesma coisa, mas como eu já usei o `git diff` e sei que ele gera um patch, preferi confiar no que eu já sabia :)

Comment: Ok, sem problemas, vou testar aqui, depois eu volto falando se deu certo ou não.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Eu não consegui aplicar o patch com o comando

```
$ git apply --check <nome-do-patch>.patch
```

Então, eu dei uma buscada aqui e encontrei um outro, que funcionou pra mim

```
$ patch -p1 < <nome-do-arquivo>.patch
```

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar =)

Comment: que bom que te ajudou! :D